# building QtSerialPort only creates debug dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I'm having trouble whilst following the instructions here for Visual Studio 2010: http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort

I'm finding that after using qmake & nmake with VS2010 only the debug version is built.  The release folder is created, but only contains QtSerialPort.prl

I did have to modify the code and drop in qwineventnotifier_p.h as this wasn't found when I first tried to build, although I don't think that this is related.

The debug version is working fine in QT on VS2010.  Any thoughts on how to get the release version up?

Comment: This is the release makefile: http://pastebin.com/zEpYtEKy

Comment: have you tried to play with following qmake CONFIG parameters - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config ? maybe, direct specifying of "qmake CONFIG+=release" will help ... also you need be sure that your make files are regenerated

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have much luck with this, but I managed to bodge it by creating the release dll in QT Creator and dropping them alongside the debug one.

Comment: The wikipage is sadly terribly outdated that we wrote. :( Which version of the library are you using?